# Why does pelican/jinja2 not set the variable again?

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I have the following script:

```
<div class="blog-archives">
    {% set last_year = 0 %}
    {% for article in dates %}
        {% set year = article.date.strftime('%Y') %}
        {% if last_year != year %}
            <h2 id="{{year }}" title="last_year={{last_year}}"><a href="#{{year}}">{{ year }}</a></h2>
            {% set last_year = year %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set next_year = 0 %}
        {% if not loop.last %}
            {% set next = loop.index0 + 1 %}
            {% set next_article = dates[next] %}
            {% set next_year = next_article.date.strftime('%Y') %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if next_year != year %}
            <article class="last-entry-of-year">
        {% else %}
            <article>
        {% endif %}
        <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }} {%if article.subtitle %} <small> {{ article.subtitle }} </small> {% endif %} </a>
        <time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="{{ article.date.isoformat() }}">{{ article.locale_date }}</time>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

which I thought would result in something like this:

[image]

But actually I get

[image]

The problem is that `{% set last_year = year %}` seems not to be executed - the value of `last_year` is always 0. Does anybody know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Python, in Jinja2 a `for` loop have its own namespace; therefore the variables you set within the loop is local to the loop, and once outside the loop, the variable of the same name would revert to the one of the outer scope.

You can use the `namespace` object to get around this issue:

```
{% set ns = namespace(last_year=0) %}
{% for article in dates %}
    {% set year = article.date.strftime('%Y') %}
    {% if ns.last_year != year %}
        <h2 id="{{year }}" title="last_year={{ns.last_year}}"><a href="#{{year}}">{{ year }}</a></h2>
        {% set ns.last_year = year %}
```

Please see the documentation of [`namespace`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments) for details.